# Как правильно именовать делегаты?

Tags: c#

Есть класс, который что-то делает и я хочу дать пользователю возможность в некоторых местах повлиять на дальнейшую работу этого класса.

Я хочу для этого дела выставить наружу поля типа делегат, куда бы пользователь мог присвоить свои обработчики, которые будут вызываться внутри класса.

Правда, я не понимаю, как в таком случае их правильно именовать? Добавлять приставку On?

Например, `OnPreRender`, `OnRdy`...

И вообще, правильно ли так делать и есть другой вариант дать пользователю из вне повлиять на код?

Comment: `я хочу дать пользователю возможность в некоторых местах повлиять на дальнейшую работу этого класса` - это делается при помощи `override` нужных методов. Делегаты как по мне не для этого созданы. По поводу именования, лично я придерживаюсь чему то вроде [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346124/6808809).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну тогда наследование нужно делать, а я не хочу, что бы наследовались...

Comment: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/events-and-callbacks), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces#names-of-common-types), [3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-events), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346065/5045688), [5](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/299101).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ т.е не правильно давать пользователю возможность полям типа делегат присваивать конкретные обработчики, что бы повлиять на логику? А есть где-то какая-то выдержка из код стайла?

Comment: Например, можно же какие-то стратегии повесить в открыте поля делегатов, что бы потом объект сам что-то делал с их использованием.